# apk has been crash while release to test but working fine in debug

Tags: reactjs, react-native, facebook, devops

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC1iT.jpg)error show like this
I can't find out whats the error

I have change my gradle version and target sdk version as well

Report bug

java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Invalid
regular expression: invalid group specifier name

at
com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCall
ExceptionHandler.handleException(Unknown Source:
9)

at
com.facebook.react.devsupport.b.handleException(
Unknown Source:2)

at
com.facebook.react.bridge.Catalystinstancelmpl.on
NativeException(Unknown Source:2)

at
com.facebook.react.bridge.Catalystinstancelmpl.ac
cess$1100(Unknown Source:0)

at
com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystinstancelmpISN
ativeExceptionHandler.handleException(Unknown
Source:2)

at
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueTh
readHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:7)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)

at
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueTh
readlmpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by:
com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Invalid
regular expression: invalid group specifier name

at
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.ru
n(Native Method)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you found anything? I'm getting the same issue when updating to RN 0.70.8